# How to call a function by its name (std::string) in C++?

Tags: c++, string, function, invoke, code-cleanup

I wonder if there is a simple way to call a function from a string. I know a simple way, using 'if' and 'else'.

```
int function_1(int i, int j) {
    return i*j;
}

int function_2(int i, int j) {
    return i/j;
}

...
...
...

int function_N(int i, int j) {
    return i+j;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    int i = 4, j = 2;
    string function = "function_2";
    cout << callFunction(i, j, function) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This is the basic approach

```
int callFunction(int i, int j, string function) {
    if(function == "function_1") {
        return function_1(i, j);
    } else if(function == "function_2") {
        return function_2(i, j);
    } else if(...) {

    } ...
    ...
    ...
    ...
    return  function_1(i, j);
}
```

Is there something simpler?

```
/* New Approach */
int callFunction(int i, int j, string function) {
    /* I need something simple */
    return function(i, j);
}
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

What you have described is called ***reflection*** and C++ doesn't support it. However you might come with some work-around, for example in this very concrete case you might use an `std::map` that would map names of functions (`std::string` objects) to function pointers, which in case of functions with the very same prototype could be easier than it might seem:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int add(int i, int j) { return i+j; }
int sub(int i, int j) { return i-j; }

typedef int (*FnPtr)(int, int);

int main() {
    // initialization:
    std::map<std::string, FnPtr> myMap;
    myMap["add"] = add;
    myMap["sub"] = sub;

    // usage:
    std::string s("add");
    int res = myMap[s](2,3);
    std::cout << res;
}
```

Note that `myMap[s](2,3)` retrieves the function pointer mapped to string `s` and invokes this function, passing `2` and `3` to it, making the output of this example to be `5`

Comment: You can improve that slightly using std::function and the initializer lists syntax.

Comment: @LokiAstari: `std::function` is C++11 I guess.

Comment: @LihO: I like your approach. Thank you.

Comment: @LokiAstari: I'll check on `std::function`

Comment: @AlanValejo: It is possible that you don't have C++11 support available. Try `#include <functional>` and if it doesn't work, try `#include <tr1/functional>`

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. But I've never see 'tr1', I need to check. 'tr1' works on linux?

Comment: @AlanValejo: tr1 stands for technical report, which might allow you to use some C++11 features even when C++11 is not yet supported. However it's possible that neither TR1 will be available.

Comment: If the function belongs to a class would: map["name"] = class->func?

Comment: @AlanValejo: It would be more something like `obj->(*map["name"])()`

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19480281/how-to-call-a-function-by-its-name-an-approach-using-stlmap-and-class

Answer (score 31):

Using a map of standard string to standard functions.

```
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int add(int x, int y) {return x+y;}
int sub(int x, int y) {return x-y;}

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::function<int(int,int)>>  funcMap =
         {{ "add", add},
          { "sub", sub}
         };

    std::cout << funcMap["add"](2,3) << "\n";
    std::cout << funcMap["sub"](5,2) << "\n";
}
```

Even better with Lambda:

```
#include <functional>
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::map<std::string, std::function<int(int,int)>>  funcMap =
         {{ "add", [](int x, int y){return x+y;}},
          { "sub", [](int x, int y){return x-y;}}
         };

    std::cout << funcMap["add"](2,3) << "\n";
    std::cout << funcMap["sub"](5,2) << "\n";
}
```

Comment: @AlanValejo: Of course it is :) Many things became far cleaner in C++11

Comment: Is it possible to use that with strings or boost::any?

Comment: @Lixt It is already using `std::string` not sure why you want to use `boost::any` in this context.

Answer (score 7):

You can also put your functions into a shared library. You will load such library dynamically with dlopen() and then just make the calls to the functions with a std::string. Here an example:

hello.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" void hello() {
    std::cout << "hello" << '\n';
}
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main() {
    using std::cout;
    using std::cerr;

    cout << "C++ dlopen demo\n\n";

    // open the library
    cout << "Opening hello.so...\n";
    void* handle = dlopen("./hello.so", RTLD_LAZY);

    if (!handle) {
        cerr << "Cannot open library: " << dlerror() << '\n';
        return 1;
    }

    // load the symbol
    cout << "Loading symbol hello...\n";
    typedef void (*hello_t)();

    // reset errors
    dlerror();

    std::string yourfunc("hello"); // Here is your function

    hello_t hello = (hello_t) dlsym(handle, yourfunc.c_str());
    const char *dlsym_error = dlerror();
    if (dlsym_error) {
        cerr << "Cannot load symbol 'hello': " << dlsym_error <<
            '\n';
        dlclose(handle);
        return 1;
    }

    // use it to do the calculation
    cout << "Calling hello...\n";
    hello();

    // close the library
    cout << "Closing library...\n";
    dlclose(handle);
}
```

compilation:

```
g++ -fPIC -shared hello.cpp -o hello.so
```

and:

```
g++ main.cpp -o main -ldl
```

run:

```
C++ dlopen demo

Opening hello.so...
Loading symbol hello...
Calling hello...
hello
Closing library...
```

The example was stolen from [here](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/thesolution.html). [There](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/C++-dlopen/index.html) you can find more detailed explanation on dlopen() and c++

Comment: I suspect this is how Unreal Engine does; it as it creates a .dll of the game which probably contains the game-specific code that it can then reference. For example, in the input handling where you can bind a function by name as a string to an input action.

Answer (score 4):

There is another possibility which hasn't been mentioned yet, which is **true** reflection.

An option for this is accessing functions exported from an executable or a shared library using operating system functions for resolving names to addresses. This has interesting uses like loading two 'contestant' dlls into an 'umpire' program, so that people can slug it out by having their actual codes fight each other (playing Reversi or Quake, whatever).

Another option is accessing the debug information created by the compiler. Under Windows this can be surprisingly easy for compilers that are compatible, since all the work can be off-loaded to system dlls or free dlls downloadable from Microsoft. Part of the functionality is already contained in the Windows API.

However, that falls more into the category of Systems Programming - regardless of language - and thus it pertains to C++ only insofar as it is the Systems Programming language par excellence.

Comment: This seems almost like a missing part of my answer above, which is exactly what my answer does as well but in a different way: "using operating system functions for resolving names to addresses" except mine simply is direct and requires your own 'algorithm' to decode a string to an address.

Comment: The point of the **reflection** idea is to access meta data created by the compiler instead of having to define tables with function names and pointers. Besides exported names and debug symbols there's also RTTI (with some compilers), and also hybrid approaches like processing the .map file created by the compiler for mapping between function names and addresses. The JEDI project does this for stack walks but it can also be used to find addresses for names instead. The idea is to use compiler-generated data that reflects the source code instead of having to define one's own tables.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to jav's answer, but loading functions from the current program:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <dlfcn.h>

extern "C"
void test()
{
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << "\n";
}

extern "C"
void test2()
{
    std::cout << __func__ << "\n";
}

void something_the_user_is_not_supposed_to_call()
{
    std::cout << "Oops...\n";
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc < 2)
    {
        std::cout << "Usage: " << argv[0] << " [function_name]\n";
        return 1;
    }

    void* self = dlopen(nullptr, RTLD_LAZY);

    if (!self)
    {
        std::cerr << dlerror() << "\n";
        return 1;
    }

    void* function = dlsym(self, argv[1]);
    
    if (!function)
    {
        std::cerr << dlerror() << "\n";
        return 1;
    }

    reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(function)();

    dlclose(self);
}
```

Then compile with the `-rdynamic` option so all symbols are exported:

```
$ g++ test.cpp -o test -ldl -rdynamic
```

And it works:

```
$ ./test test
void test()
$ ./test test2
test2
$ ./test test3
./test: undefined symbol: test3
```

Of course, doing this is a terrible idea:

```
$ ./test _Z42something_the_user_is_not_supposed_to_callv
Oops...
$ ./test abort
Aborted (core dumped)
$ ./test sleep
^C
$ ./test main
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```