# How to call a function by its name. An approach using STL::map and Class

Tags: c++, code-cleanup

Based on post [How to call a function by its name (std::string) in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473313/how-to-call-a-function-by-its-name-stdstring-in-c/19473354?noredirect=1#comment28890934_19473354), tried to make a version using CLASS, but my approach does not work.

```
class A {
    public:
        int add(int i, int j) { return i+j; }
        int sub(int i, int j) { return i-j; }
};

typedef int (*FnPtr)(int, int);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

// initialization:
std::map<std::string, FnPtr> myMap;
A a;
myMap["add"] = a.add;
myMap["sub"] = a.sub;
```

Returns this erro:

```
main.cpp:31:22: error: cannot convert ‘A::add’ from type ‘int (A::)(int, int)’ to type ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char>, int (*)(int, int)>::mapped_type {aka int (*)(int, int)}’
main.cpp:32:22: error: cannot convert ‘A::sub’ from type ‘int (A::)(int, int)’ to type ‘std::map<std::basic_string<char>, int (*)(int, int)>::mapped_type {aka int (*)(int, int)}’
```

Does anyone know what is the error?

Comment: Member functions are not functions. You cannot *call* a member function (like "`myMap["add"](1, 2)`"), because that makes no sense. Instead, you need to combine the *class member* `A::add` and the instance object `a` in some way.

Comment: A pointer-to-member is not the same as a pointer-to-non-member. But you would have been able to find this yourself if you had googled the compiler error. Change `typedef int (*FnPtr)(int, int);` to `typedef int (A::*FnPtr)(int, int);` and call it like `a.*(myMap["add"])(42, 1337);`. Horrible, isn't it?

Comment: You have a more fundamental problem here: member functions are not the same as non-member functions.

Comment: Use perhaps `std::function` + `std::bind`

Comment: Are *all* your functions members of `class A`?

Comment: `class A` can have many functions

Answer (score 2):

At least as you've shown things, your `class A` provides nothing but problems. If you turn it into a namespace, things will be a lot easier.

```
namespace A {
    int add(int i, int j) { return i+j; }
    int sub(int i, int j) { return i-j; }
};

typedef int (*FnPtr)(int, int);

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    std::map<std::string, FnPtr> myMap;
    myMap["add"] = A::add;
    myMap["sub"] = A::sub;
    // ...
```

This way, `add` and `sub` aren't member functions, so you don't get the type mismatch. At least as shown, the instance of `A` provided no functionality beyond calling `add` and `sub`, so a namespace accomplishes just as much good while eliminating the problems.

Comment: Nice and straight-forward. Static class members would provide a similar alternative, with the benefit of being templatable.

Answer (score 0):

You could also solve the problem, as mentioned by Kal in the comments, using std::function and std::bind(this is C++11 so):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

class A {
    public:
        int add(int i, int j) { return i+j; }
        int sub(int i, int j) { return i-j; }
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  std::map<std::string, std::function<int(int,int)>> myMap;
  A a;
  myMap["add"] = std::bind(&A::add,&a,std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2);
  myMap["sub"] = std::bind(&A::sub,&a,std::placeholders::_1,std::placeholders::_2);

  std::cout<<myMap["sub"](7,2)<<std::endl;
}
```