# Is there a simple way to implement it in C++?

Tags: c++

I want to implement a function that can print out the value of one member variable (for example, 'aa') of struct ('Data') by it's name.
I try to use the macro definition as follows, but failed.
Is there a simple way to implement it?

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Data
{
    int aa;
    int bb;
    int cc;
    Data(): aa(1),bb(2),cc(3) {};
};

#define Param(a,b) a.##b

void Process(Data& data, const string& name)
{
    cout << Param(data, name) << endl;
}

void main()
{
    Data data;

    Process(data, "aa");//I want print the value of Data.aa
    Process(data, "bb");//I want print the value of Data.bb
    Process(data, "cc");//I want print the value of Data.cc
}
```

Comment: You can declare functions inside a struct, just as you whould do in a class

Comment: Just call the process function with parameter `data.aa`

Comment: The actual situation is more complex than this, can not be called directly.

Comment: No, C++ does not provide a simple way to implement this. In fact, as far as i know it provides no way of implementing this at all

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to call a function by its name (std::string) in C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473313/how-to-call-a-function-by-its-name-stdstring-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in C++.

This kind of usage is generally seen in scripting languages.

In C++ the variable names are constructed at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Your original code sample makes no sense to me because if you call `Param(name)` then the compiler has to know what instance of `Data` it has to use to determine the value of the member variable you want to get the value of (but I'm neither an expert using macros nor do I like them very much).

I tried to solve your problem using the following approach:

```
struct Data
{
    int aa;
};

#define GetMemberValue(d, n) d.##n

int main()
{
    Data d;

    d.aa = 3;

    int i = GetMemberValue(d, aa);
}
```

At least this approach returns the right result in this case.

Another thing is that you stated that you cannot call the member variables directly i.e. `data.aa` so you might run into the same issue using the macro. It's just a guess as I don't know the original code you're using.

Comment: Yes, I found it! I've changed it.