# Dynamicly setting which parameter to extract

Tags: c++, c++11

Having structure

```
struct Person{
   Person(int a , int i):age(a),id(i){};
   int age;
   int id;
}
```

Is it possible to pass which argument to exctract as argument in function? Something like

```
int extract( Person * p , param ){
    return p -> param;
}
```

which would return id , if used it like

```
extract( p , "id" )
```

and age if i used it like

```
exctract(p , "age")
```

Is something like this possible in c++?

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [How can I call a method given only its name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473313/how-to-call-a-function-by-its-name-stdstring-in-c)

Answer (score 4):

You can use pointers to class members.

```
struct Person{
    Person(int a , int i):age(a),id(i){};
    int age;
    int id;
};

int extract(Person* p, int Person::* param)
{
    return p->*param;
}
```

and you'd use it like this:

```
extract(p, &Person::id);
```

[demo](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/M65ixexHbUJyeuQo)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with preprocessor abuse, and more notably, without using string comparisons, which seems like what you want to do.

```
#include <iostream>

#define extract(p, i) (p->i)

struct Person{
  int age;
  int id;
};

int main() {
  Person p;
  p.age = 100;
  p.id = 30;
  std::cout << extract((&p), id) << '\n' << extract((&p), age) << '\n';
}
```

Not that I suggest doing this, though.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Map<char*, int>`which can do exactly that (but arguably is a bit of owerkill).
Or just plain  `char[][]` and check equality with the parameter in a `for` loop.