# C++ Shell interface

Tags: c++, shell, c++11

I'm building an application where the interface is like a shell. The idea is to write the function name and the function is called. I saw a post in stackoverflow (see below) that explains a way to do this storing the function pointer.
I'm storing my functions in a map of type `std::map<std::string, std::function<void(const std::vector<std:.string>, const std::map<std:.string, std::string>)> >` but when I compile it gives the follwing error

```
error: could not convert ‘{{"exit", ((GitDeploy::Shell*)this)->GitDeploy::Shell::exit}, {"help", ((GitDeploy::Shell*)this)->GitDeploy::Shell::help}, {"dbinfo", ((GitDeploy::Shell*)this)->GitDeploy::Shell::dbinfo}, {"list", ((GitDeploy::Shell*)this)->GitDeploy::Shell::list}, {"create", ((GitDeploy::Shell*)this)->GitDeploy::Shell::create}, {"update", ((GitDeploy::Shell*)this)->GitDeploy::Shell::update}, {"remove", ((GitDeploy::Shell*)this)->GitDeploy::Shell::remove}}’ from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘const std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::function<void(std::vector<std::basic_string<char> >, std::map<std::basic_string<char>, std::basic_string<char> >)> >’
         };
```

## shell.h

```
#ifndef SHELL_CLASS
#define SHELL_CLASS
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

namespace GitDeploy {

    class Shell {
        private:
            std::map<std::string, std::function<void(const std::vector<std::string>, const std::map<std::string, std::string>)> > const methods {
                {"exit", exit},
                {"help", help},
                {"dbinfo", dbinfo},
                {"list", list},
                {"create", create},
                {"update", update},
                {"remove", remove}
            };

            std::map<std::string, std::string> const method_help {
                {"exit", "Exists GitDeploy"},
                {"help", "Prints available commands"},
                {"dbinfo", "Prints database information"},
                {"list", "Lists repositories."},
                {"create", "Adds a new repository"},
                {"update", "Updates a existing repositor\nyou must pass is uuid or partial uuid and the values to update\nupdate <uuid> path=<path> reset=<reset>"},
                {"remove", "Deletes a repository\nTo delete a repository, pass the uuids or partial uuids to delete\ndelete <uuid> <uuid> [...]"}
            };

            bool exit_shell;
        public:
            void serve();

            void exit(const std::vector<std::string>, const std::map<std::string, std::string>);
            void help(const std::vector<std::string>, const std::map<std::string, std::string>);
            void dbinfo(const std::vector<std::string>, const std::map<std::string, std::string>);
            void list(const std::vector<std::string>, const std::map<std::string, std::string>);
            void create(const std::vector<std::string>, const std::map<std::string, std::string>);
            void update(const std::vector<std::string>, const std::map<std::string, std::string>);
            void remove(const std::vector<std::string>, const std::map<std::string, std::string>);
    };
}

#endif
```

## Answer to StackOverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19473313/how-to-call-a-function-by-its-name-stdstring-in-c)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

int add(int i, int j) { return i+j; }
int sub(int i, int j) { return i-j; }

typedef int (*FnPtr)(int, int);

int main() {
    // initialization:
    std::map<std::string, FnPtr> myMap;
    myMap["add"] = add;
    myMap["sub"] = sub;

    // usage:
    std::string s("add");
    int res = myMap[s](2,3);
    std::cout << res;
}
```

Thanks,

Hugo Rodrigues

Comment: The abuse of `eof` in that code and the pointless top-level qualifiers on function parameters worry me a great deal.

Comment: No, post a [mcve] as part of the question, instead of dumping a link to some external web site that can stop working at any time, rendering the question meaningless. Having said that, and without looking at some external site, it looks to me like these are not functions, but class methods, and the problem is very obvious.

Comment: I am worried about all those C casts. They are probably not correct.

Comment: FWIW, I usually go with a lambda that captures 'this' when wanting to save a member function as an object.

Comment: I'm starting with c++, thats why I have some issues in my code
@SamVarshavchik the post was a Stack Overflow one, thats why I posted a  link. I edited the question to fix it. Yes they are class methods, how can I do it to store the method on the map?

Comment: The "entire project" link most definitely does not go to stackoverflow.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Yes I know, it't going to GitHub, I thought that refering it may be helpfull

Comment: It is not just helpful, it contains all the pertinent information that's needed to understand this question. That's the issue. It's going to get downvoted, until it's replaced by a [mcve]. I didn't make the rules. An external link is fine, but only if it's completely optional.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Hmmm alright, sorry. I fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fix it by converting the methods to static