# cannot convert ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to

Tags: c++, function-pointers, overload-resolution

This question relates to [Call a class method inside a function which was passed as a string parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73647863/call-a-class-method-inside-a-function-which-was-passed-as-a-string-parameter)

I have two class hierarchies.
The most base classes for each are `obj_t` and `obj2_t`.

I have a generic template

```
template<typename retval_t>
retval_t obj2_t::getProperty(
        const obj_t& obj,
        const retval_t (obj2_t::*fProp)(const vec_t&, const string&, const int) const,
        const retval_t (obj_t::*fAggregate)(const retval_t&) const,
        const vec_t& vec,
        const string& s,
        const int i)
{
    retval_t retval = getPropertySingle<retval_t>(fProp, vec, s, i);
    return (obj.*fAggregate)(retval);
};
```

Each `fProp` has its corresponding `fAggregate`.
I want to use the method as

```
int obj2_t::getX(
        const obj_t& obj,
        const vec_t& vec,
        const string& s,
        const int i)
{
    int retval = getProperty<int>(obj, &obj2_t::getXSingle, &obj_t::AggregateX, vec, s, i);
    return retval;
};
```

It worked fine in one case.
But in another case where `AggregateX` was overloaded in class `obj_t` I got compilation error `cannot convert ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ to ...`
even if there was no ambiguity in which overload was usable.

**Why do I need to specify the overload, and how do I do that?**

Extra "curiosity" question:
**Are there other problematic cases (not solved with the same solution as this) that appear when passing derived classes for `obj`?**

Comment: please post [mcve] which **reproduce the error**. DON'T just describe what not work.

Comment: how exactly the overloaded functions are different?

Comment: @TheDreamsWind - I will make an effort in meeting the ends of a complex (but actual) code and a MCVE that keeps the relevant features (to the best of my knowledge, which is by no means a guarantee!)

Comment: @TheDreamsWind - Found the problem. `AggregateX` had two overloads.
For the target case (`retval_t = int`) it was taking a `const int` instead of a `const int&`.
That is why the overload could not be resolved. Fixed that. Thanks!

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio keep it up! :)