# store pointers to such functions that can have any return type and also can have different number of parameters of any type

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, stdmap

I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19473354/18774119) post, and it is some what I am trying to do, but "**I want a map that can store pointers to such functions that can have any return type and also can have different number of parameters of any type (mainly Multitype as shown below in the code)**". I was trying to do something below (overloading typedef). The code below doesn't work though.

```
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <map>

#include <iostream>
#include <map>
using namespace boost;

typedef boost::variant<int, float, double, std::string> MultiType;
typedef MultiType (*FnPtr)(MultiType, MultiType);
typedef MultiType(*FnPtr)(MultiType, MultiType, MultiType);

MultiType add(MultiType i, MultiType j) { return get<int>(i) + get<int>(j);}
MultiType sub(MultiType i, MultiType j) { return get<int>(i) - get<int>(j);}
MultiType str(std::string s) { return s; }

int main() {
    // initialization:
    std::map<std::string, FnPtr> myMap;
    myMap["add"] = add;
    myMap["sub"] = sub;
    myMap["str"] = str;

    // usage:
    std::string s("add");
    int res = myMap[s](2, 3);
    std::cout << res;
}
```

Comment: You forgot to include something very important in your question: an actual question. A very close read of what you wrote above reveals a narrative, some code, but no question, whatsoever? What is your question? The post that you "came across" explains, succinctly, that C++ simply doesn't work this way. So, what is your question about that?

Comment: You can use `std::variant` or `std::any` to map N/all types to a single "value type".

Comment: I don't think in C++ it is possible to store functions with different signatures in a container (at least not without casting it depending on the key). But maybe some template magic guru can prove me wrong.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik "I want a map that can store pointers to such functions that can have any return type and also can have different number of parameters of any type"

Comment: C++ does not work this way, sorry, as explained in the other post. In C++ every object's type must be specified at compile-time. This is fundamental to C++. There are no exceptions, or workarounds. By the way: Google-based programming doesn't work very well. You might get some search results mentioning something about `std::any`. But after investing some time in figuring out what it is, and how it works, the eventual conclusion will be: nope, that doesn't work that way, either.

Comment: Not quite an exactly duplicate, but `AnyCallable<std::any>` answers the question in the title. Whilst you can do this, I really recommend not.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik you *can* throw away all the type information, it just becomes obnoxious to use.

Comment: Suppose you succeed in creating such a map. What do you want to do with it? Show (pseudo)code examples.